# How to change the radio group checked circle to tick mark in ionic 5

Tags: angular, ionic5

I'm working in ionic 5 and I want to change the checked radio circle to tick mark to match the ux design, please help me on this.
Here is the code.

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-radio-group>
    <ion-list-header>
      <ion-label>
        Auto Manufacturers
      </ion-label>
    </ion-list-header>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Cord</ion-label>
      <ion-radio value="cord"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Duesenberg</ion-label>
      <ion-radio value="duesenberg"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Hudson</ion-label>
      <ion-radio value="hudson"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Packard</ion-label>
      <ion-radio value="packard"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Studebaker</ion-label>
      <ion-radio value="studebaker"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-radio-group>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `mode` property for `ion-radio` can be forced to set it to iOS which uses checks instead of the normal "radio" style.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/radio#properties

> mode
> Description
> The mode determines which platform styles to use.
>
> Attribute mode
> Type  "ios" | "md"

```html
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Cord</ion-label>
  <ion-radio mode="ios" value="cord"></ion-radio>
</ion-item>
```

I don't think thats the best design choice, since checkboxes and radio buttons have different UI meanings and interactions, but I guess iOS does it that way.

Here's an example stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-y8wjvk